# Can I write a file names to one variable and the text to a second variable using PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to update 28 insert statements we use in our data warehouse ETL. The 28 .sql files are saved in a folder with each job_name as the file name.
Can I make the file name a variable and make the sql file into a second (CLOB) variable?
If I can do that I can loop through the 28 files and UPDATE the SQL where vFileName = job_name.
I'm quite new to PL/SQL so please use small words:-)

For now my only approach is 28 discrete

```
UPDATE etl_script from LOAD_SCRIPTS where JOB_NAME = file1;
```

I'd love to automate this!

---

Additional info:

Our DW uses LSF to schedule execution of scripts. Scripts are stored in the JOBS table. I need to update 28 of the rows in JOBS to replace the existing scripts with my new scripts. This will do the job one file at a time:

```
UPDATE JOBS SET SCRIPT= new_sql_script WHERE JOB_NAME= job1;
```

I can just run this 28 times... I'd like to loop through the 28 files from a shared server and load each script into variables and run the UPDATE to update each of the 28 rows one at a time. Files are named JOB1, JOB2 etc

From documentation is UTL_FILE FOPEN and GET_RAW the right functionality to investigate?

Comment: _I'm quite new to PL/SQL_ Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/index.html#Oracle%C2%AE-Database)?

Comment: Let's check whether I correctly understood the problem.

Currently, there are 28 SQL files in some folder. File names contain "job name" (for example. `manager.sql`, `clerk.sql` etc.). Each of them does *whatever it does*, and does it correctly. However, in order to do it, you have to run each of these files separately, one-by-one.

If that's so, why do you think that you should involve **Oracle** (PL/SQL) into it? To me, it looks as if you should write an operating system (OS) batch script which would do it. And then, it depends on OS itself (code differs from MS Windows to Linux to ...).

Comment: please add a small example to the question

Comment: Our DW uses LSF to schedule execution of scripts. Scripts are stored in the JOBS table. I need to update 28 of the rows  in JOBS to replace the existing scripts with my new scripts. This will do the job one file at a time:
UPDATE JOBS
SET SCRIPT= new_sql_script
WHERE JOB_NAME= job1;
I can just run this 28 times...
I'd like to loop through the 28 files from a shared server and load each script into variables and run the UPDATE to update each of the 28 rows one at a time. Files are named JOB1, JOB2 etc
From documentation is UTL_FILE FOPEN and GET_RAW the right functionality to investigate?

Comment: I've updated your question with the infos you gave and tagged it Oracle. Feel free to make corrections. It looks like you need a stored procedure with a cursor and for loop, but I don't know exactly where you want to go.